# How can I bypass login page for Superset when using OAuth2 for authentication?

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, okta, apache-superset

I am using Superset 0.36 and set up successfully OAUTH2 login using my SSO- Okta. However the redirect uri http://[site]:8088/oauth-authorized/okta that needs to be configured for Flask Application Builder to work redirects to a login page where the user needs to choose a provider and click sign-in. This is an unnecessary step since the user already logged into OKTA and should not need to login again.

Can someone help with any FAB configuration that would help set up an auto login using OAUTH2 so that we can bypass this redundant login page which my users find confusing and sometimes get stuck on. If there is no way to bypass it can someone tell me how I can customize the login page to instruct users how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (although not with Okta, and version 0.37). From the javascript in that login page I figured out the final URL. Look at the `signin` function that’s called when you click the button:

```
function signin() {
    if (currentSelection != "") {
        window.location.href = baseLoginUrl + currentSelection + next;
    }
}
```

In your case I guess it would be something like:

http://[site]:8088/login/okta/?next=[dashboard]

**Disclaimer**: I’m absolutely not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but in my case it was just a POC so it didn’t matter much.

Also you should make sure you understand those 3 settings in `superset_config.py` regarding the Superset session cookie behavior in HTTP vs. HTTPS:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

And of course this makes sense only if you want to allow 1 authentication provider.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  However, this function, if I understand correctly, gets fired when clicking on the "Sign In" button on the Sign In page which I am trying to bypass so I am not sure how this will bypass the page which is my aim. Nevertheless, I tried what you said above but I cannot get it to work anyway.

Comment: I was just explaining how to figure out the final URL from that javascript, i.e. the URL you should put in the iframe `src`, to effectively bypass the need for clicking.

Comment: Yeh, I figured that and am going to try to add this the redirect uri

Comment: Here is my redirect uri but it is not going to the dashboard list:
http://[site]/oauth-authorized/okta/?next=%2Fdashboard%2Flist%2F
But I still get the sign in page :(. @Jeff

Comment: Mine reads `http://localhost:8080/login/auth0`. In `OAUTH_PROVIDERS` in `superset_config.py` I have a single entry whose name is `auth0`. Maybe also validate against all constants starting with `AUTH_` here: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset/config.py

Comment: My only entry in OAUTH_PROVIDERS is "okta" but after much trial and error in the past found that on the Okta side needed a redirect URI configured to match exactly " http://[site]/oauth-authorized/okta"; otherwise FAB would not accept it. Are you using OAUTH2 and the AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH? I can try using "login/okta" but what does your /?next= part of URL look like? @Jeff

Comment: Yes AUTH_OAUTH. My `next` is http://localhost:8080/superset/dashboard/world_health/?standalone=true.